# How to pass variable holding a value to groovy eq query?

Tags: grails, groovy

How can I pass variable holding a value instead of passing a value directly to groovy search criteria?

```
for (def payee in payees)
{
    def results = resp.cases.find("eq 'hrid','7547') // hard code values work
    def results = resp.cases.find("eq 'hrid',??????) // how can I pass payee
}
```

I'm new to this. Please help. thanks

Comment: This isn't valid code, you have an unclosed double-quote before `eq`.  I'm not familiar with this eq query either, can you provide a link to some documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Basing on [examples](http://grails.asia/groovy-find), check it:

```
def results = resp.cases.find { case -> case.hrid == payee }
```

Answer (score 0):

GORM criteria queries are quite different than your example. Let's say you have a `Payee` domain class with a property named *hrid*:

**grails-app/domain/com/something/Payee.groovy**

```
class Payee {
    String hrid
}
```

To get a list of all the `Payee` instances with an `hrid` of *7547*, you'd run a criteria query like this:

```
String hridValue = '7547'

List payees = Payee.withCriteria {
    eq 'hrid', hridValue
}
```

I explain Grails GORM queries in depth in a series of articles starting right [here](http://emmanuelrosa.com/articles/gorm-for-sqladdicts-where-clause/).